# Mockito.when().thenReturn() not working as expected

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, junit, mocking, mockito

New to Mockito.

I am testing a function inside class A, inside the class A constructor, I have class B. (I need to use a method from class B). Here's the code:

```
class A @Inject constructor(
    private val bAccessor: B
)

fun buildInfo(number, name): Map<String,String> {
    val graph = bAccessor.getGraph(
        number,
        name
    )
    val filters = GraphParser.getRefinement(graph)
    return filters.entries.associate {
        val bin = it.key to Bin
            .builder()
            .withRestrict(it.value)
            .build()
        bin
    }
}
```

My unit test is testing the class A - buildInfo function,

Below is my unit test code:

```
@Mock
private lateinit var graph: Graph

@Mock
private lateinit var b: B

@InjectMocks
private lateinit var a: A

@BeforeEach
fun setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
}

@Test
    fun `test buildInfo`() {
        `when`(b.getGraph("123456", "Test")).thenReturn(graph)

         var info = a.buildInfo("123456", "Test")
 
         assertTrue(info.isNotEmpty())
         assertTrue(info.containsKey("refinement_key"))
         assertEquals("refinement_value", info["refinement_key"])
```

The test fail because:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: 
method GraphParser.getRefinement, parameter graph
at GraphParser.getRefinement(GraphView.kt)
at A.buildInfo(A.kt:178)
```

getRefinement method can only accept the Graph object. I don't want to actually call the b, so I've mocked the answer above like this:

```
`when`(b.getGraph("123456", "Test")).thenReturn(graph)
```

But why it indicates the graph is null even if I return a graph?

Comment: Do you happen to have any annotations on your unit test class?

Answer (score 0):

A parenthesis is missed before `thenReturn`:

```
_actual: `when`(b.getGraph("123456", "Test").thenReturn(graph)

correct: `when`(b.getGraph("123456", "Test")).thenReturn(graph)
                                            ^  
                                      missed symbol
```

Comment: Just add it. Thank you. But it still throw the same error...

Comment: @dosu So the code you'd posted didn't compile, isn't it? Please provide the complete minimal example: test class with all anntations and imports plus definition of class A,B.